# General PHP/OOP Strategy - How to communicate between nested objects

Tags: php, oop

When using nested objects (ObjTwo as a property of objOne):

```
$objOne->property = new ObjTwo($objOne);
```

What's the best way to communicate?  Here are a few methods I can think of:

**Using specific get/set methods**

```
class ObjTwo {
    __construct($objOne){
        $prop1 = $objOne->get_prop1(); 
        // do something with prop1
        $prop2 = $objOne->get_prop2();
        // do something with prop2

        // ... Having to write all these out is kind of a pain
        //     if you're going to have 20+ vars, and there's no
        //     easy way to loop through them.
    }
}
```

*The problem:* Writing these out line by line, and having to update it when I add new properties.

I know that having a get/set method for each property is recommended, however I'd really like to loop through the data...

**How about get_object_vars()**

```
class ObjTwo {
    __construct($objOne){
        extract(get_object_vars($objOne));
        // do something with the vars
    }
}
```

*The problem:* This method bypasses the ability to use getter/setter methods, and each property would have to be public to be accessible.

**Dynamic getter/setter method calls**

Another way I have considered is to create an array of fields, and have a strict policy of naming the getter/setter methods:

```
class ObjTwo {
    __construct($objOne){
        $prop_array = array('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop_three');
        $values = array();
        foreach ($prop_array as $prop){
            $values[$prop] = $objOne->get_{$prop}();
        }
    }
}
```

*The problem:* Every time I add a new property, I have to make sure to name the get_method() correctly, and update the $prop_array.

**Anyone have any better solutions?  Maybe just building an array of data?:**

```
$objOne->property = new ObjTwo($objOne->get_data());
```

---

**I like this solution**

Having thought this through, here's a little clarification:  I'm not trying to just make identical copies from parent to child or vice-versa - I edited the above examples to show that a little better.  It's more just the idea of passing a subset of the object's data from one place to another.

*Instead of having to write:*

```
$first_name = $this->member->get_first_name();
$last_name = $this->member->get_last_name();
$email = $this->member->get_email();
$display_name = $this->member->get_display_name();
// etc... and
$this->member->set_first_name($first_name);
$this->member->set_last_name($last_name);
$this->member->set_email($email);
$this->member->set_display_name($display_name);
// etc..
```

How about having a `$this->member->get_fields('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'display_name');` method?  I don't like having to remember the field names exactly (fname, f_name, first_name, etc), so you could use class constants:

```
$data = $this->member->get_fields(array(
    Member::FIRST_NAME, Member::LAST_NAME, Member::EMAIL, Member::DISPLAY_NAME
));
```

This way, I can loop through the returned data.

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) // ...
```

And setting the fields...

```
$this->member->set_fields(array(
    Member::FIRST_NAME => $first_name,   //  THE BIG ADVANTAGE HERE:
    Member::LAST_NAME => $last_name,     //  These field keys auto-complete
    Member::EMAIL => $email,             //  so you don't have to remember them!
    Member::DISPLAY_NAME => $display_name,
    // etc...
));
```

Still thinking this through... any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to clarify your definition of "communication". What is your final goal? That `ObjOne` instances expose the members of the `ObjTwo` instance that it holds?

Comment: What do you want to *do* anyway? Are you trying to assign all properties of object A to object B? Why?!

Comment: Why do you want to copy the first object into second? Two objects communicate via methods or via a publish/subscribe strategy

Comment: I agree, the first pass was a bit misleading.  Making an identical copy isn't the goal, but often a subset of the data needs to be transmitted.  I made some edits to reflect a more generalized usage.  Also, I added an answer that I'm thinking about implementing, interested in any opinions.

Comment: The whole mapping idea is wrong, you don't need to do that. Using constants is not a good idea either, a) because the whole thing is not needed and b) because constants are what they are... not variables.

Comment: Hey @markus-tharkun, I appreciate your feedback - WordPress makes liberal use of this method, passing an argument array which accepts a variable set of properties.  They do this for a wide range of things:  querying posts, saving data, etc.

Comment: The one annoying thing about WordPress, is that you have to look up the proper keys.  Is it 'userlogin' or 'user_login'?  These constants will never change and are purely for autocomplete.

Comment: a) Wordpress is NOT well written PHP. b) passing and injecting argument arrays for configuration in frameworkish circumstances can be a solution but are not the best one. In that case you should look at magic methods, which I would also not recommend very strongly.

Comment: And now I think there isn't more to say without a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. Furthermore I think it would only be possible to really help, if you provided a **real** example instead of those pseudo examples. Every real situation is different with regard to the proper solution.

Generally all your proposals smell. It seems that what you need is not injection but inheritance. If your 'child' class really needs access to all or most of the properties of another class, it seems it should extend that class.

The parts of your software should know as little as possible about each other. In your comment you mention that you have a Member class and a Form class. I don't know why any of them should know anything about the other at all.

Furthermore you seem to be under the impression that you need to map every property to a property in the new class. Why? If you pass an instance of a class into another class via custructor (= dependency injection) then you can map that instance to a property and then access all properties of the injected instance via that instance. No mapping needed.

```
class Consumer
{
    private $injectedClass;

    function __construct($injectedClass)
    {
        $this->injectedClass = $injectedClass;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        //do something by using any property of the injected class
        $this->injectedClass->getProperty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, I'm working with a Member class and Form classes, although I'm starting to branch out into a number of other class types, and in the future I will have many many more with varying structures.  So, my questions are pretty general :-\.  See my answer I just added, I'm interested in your opinion.

Comment: Post the important parts of your member class and your form class and tell us, which propoerties you think one needs to know from the other and why.

Answer (score -1):

I tend to do it like this. This may not be the best way to do it:

```
class Parent_Obj {
    $var1; // explanation
    $var2; // explanation
    $var3; // explanation
    $child_obj; // explanation

    __construction() {
        /* Do a bunch of stuff */
        $this->$child_obj = new Child_Obj ($this);
    }
}

class Child_Obj {
    $var1; // explanation
    $var2; // explanation
    $var3; // explanation
    $parent_obj; // explanation

    __construction($parent) {
        /* Do a bunch of stuff */
        $this->$parent_obj = $parent;
    }

    /* Some function that needs a method or property of the parent object */
    function some_function () { 
        /* do some stuff */
        echo $this->parent_obj->var1; // echo a property of the parent obj
    }
}
```

I believe the term for this is called "aggregation".

Comment: IMO that's not a good way. It creates circular dependencies which have to be avoided!